# For latest installation, compile from source or apt-get from PPA, which one is preferred?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I have read similar threads here. Let me be more specific.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Most packages in official source are lag far behind, eg: Nginx. I want to install the lastest stable version.

1. IMO, I love apt-get because it is centralized and easy for upgrades, but it needs to add PPA. The problem is how to determine a PPA is reliable/trusted. eg: What is the good PPA for HAProxy and keepalived? https://launchpad.net/~vbernat?
2. Does using PPA is the recommended solution in general software installation?
3. What is the difference between apt-get install and dpkg -i some.deb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo

Read through this, and do your research on the PPA.

2. No, for the reasons above. The central repositories have a ton of security checks done to ensure the safety of software.
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get

apt-get is a really smart version of dpkg that doesn't require you to download things manually and fetches dependencies automagically.

By the way, .deb files are not installing from source. Typically you start from the tarball level with source installation.